# grailsmelody plugin - private methods

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using grailsmelody plugin to monitor performance of my app. I have a private method defined in a service. When calling it, I get missingMethodException. Does grailsmelody plugin not support private methods?

```
class UserService {

    def doStuff(params) 
    {
        if(isAdmin()) { // missingMethodException because of the grailsmelody plugin
            ....
        }
    }

    private def isAdmin() {
        ....
    }

}
```

Thanks, 
Nish

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: hm. what if you change it to `private boolean isAdmin()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It had to do with how method was declared. I am not exactly sure as to why this fixed the problem.

Failed: private def isAdmin( name, Class c ) {     ....    } 
Worked: private def isAdmin( name, c ) {     ....    }

Nish